# Can you cache UIViewControllers?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, orientation

I have an application with 8 UIViewControllers presented by navigating from left/right/up/down. They are created on start of the app and kept in an NSArray. Only 1 of them is added to the view tree (addSubview:) at any time - the rest just sit in the cache until they are needed.

Now the problem I am having is when rotating to Landscape. Only the currently visible view changes the bounds.size to Landscape. When navigating to the next view, that view still thinks it is in Portrait (but the containing views will all look in Landscape).

By the way, the view hierarchy of the app is the following: UIWindow -> Main UIViewController -> 1 of the 8 cached UIViewControllers.

For example:
* Change orientation:
- Main UIViewController.view.bounds.size = 480x300 (OK)
- One of the cached UIViewControllers view.bounds.size = 480x300 (OK)
* Go to next view: 
- Main UIViewController.view.bounds.size = 480x300 (OK), 
- Another of the cached UIViewControllers view.bounds.size = 320x460 (??)

Not sure whats going on. Do I have to tell the cached UIViewControllers somehow that the orientation/size changed or something else?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why not use UINavigationController to push / pop and replace the current view ?

Comment: I am still having the problem even when using a UINavigationController. There is something else going on that prevents the view from getting resized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Optimally you should purge the view that each view controller manages when it goes off screen.

Simply assign `nil` to the `view` property of the view controller that is being replaced. This will free all resourced used by the view that is not visible anyway. As an added bonus the view is then recreated with proper frame whenever you decide to brin a particular viw controller in front again.

I am also assuming that what you are implementing is a subclass of `UIViewController` that acts as a container for other view controllers. Like a sibling to `UITabController` named `CWGridController` or similar. Noe that it is the responsibility of the the parent view controller (your subclass) to size the frame of it's child view controllers views as needed.

Creating a container view controller is not a small task, and the support for doing it is not complete from Apple. There are a few things you must do including but not limited to:

- Forward all orientation change calls to all child view controllers.
- Properly call all appear/disappear on child view controller as needed.

The last part to make it work is to break some rules. View controllers works very badly unless they know about their parent view controller, layout will be wrong and modal view controller behaves strange. Unfortunately the `parentViewController` is readonly, or so you would think. Setting it anyway using KVC will solve most problems, and Apple does not seem to object when you submit to App Store:

```
[childViewController setValue:self forKey:@"parentViewController"];
```

Comment: I tried setting nextController.view = nil when moving to next but didn't help. Yes UIViewController acts as a container for only 1 UIViewController at a time. The other UIViewController are in an array. When the user navigates next, the current UIViewController's view is removed from superview and the next is added. It is possible the problem is that I am animating using the UIView and instead should use the UIViewController to animate the transitions.

Comment: Your controller acts as a container just as `UITabBarController` is a container for many view controllers. Both only display the view from one of them at a time. Conceptually you are doing the same thing, the presentation is just different. In order for this to work as intended you **must** fulfil your obligations as a container view controller. For example you **must** call `viewDidAppear:`, `viewDidDisappear:`, etc, on the contained view controllers at proper times. Otherwise the contained view controllers can not know about their current state.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I think my whole approach is wrong. I have to rethink how I manage the view controllers in my app. I would be creating them on demand (instead of caching them) and will cache the expensive stuff within the view and model. Will take some time to rework this. Thanks.

Comment: @vance: My pleasure. Must say I admire any developer willing to go back to the drawing board in light of new info.

Answer (score 0):

In viewWillAppear you will have to check the interface orientation and set the frames accordingly.

Comment: "- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated" Only fires when I start the app - for the very first view. This might be something to do with the way the views are transitioned using [UIView beginAnimations...] and [current.view.superview addSubview:next.view] to transition to the next possibly.

Comment: Instead of adding and removing views you could try to hide the views instead. view.hidden = YES; That way, the views will still autorotate correctly.